# List index out of range, when I try to read from file

Tags: python-3.x

I have a file witch have information:

```
1;Boston
2,Denver
```

Now I try to read this information and put them on a list, code:

```
file = open(self.__file_name, 'r')
line = file.readline().rstrip('\n')
while line != " ":
    attr = line.split(';')
    city = City(attr[0], attr[1])
    self.save(city)
    line = file.readline().rstrip('\n')
```

After this I had a error IndexError: `list index out of range`

If i put a `print(attr)` after `attr = line.split(';')` the program print:

```
['1', 'Boston']
['2', 'Denver']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is hiere: `while line != " ":`, the while must me like that: `while line != "":` (without space in contition)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
file = open(self.__file_name, 'r')
line = file.readline().rstrip('\n')
while line != " ":
    attr = line.split(';')
    if len(attr) >1:


        city = City(attr[0], attr[1])
        self.save(city)
    line = file.readline().rstrip('\n')
```

Comment: i fix it... the problem was `while line != "":` without space

Comment: @Sn0pY: If you have the answer, Stack Overflow encourages you to post it.  If you don't think it will be helpful to future readers, you should delete your question.